# ios - How to parse HTML content in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, html-parsing

How do I parse HTML file?

I'm getting an HTML file in the below code,I just want to get data in between      BinarySecurityToken XML node.

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
   if(_data)
  {
    //Here am getting the below HTML content
    NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  }
 }


<input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0" />
<input type="hidden" name="wresult"
    value="<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
<t:Lifetime>
   <wsu:Created >2013-04-29T11:50:29.895Z</wsu:Created>
   <wsu:Expires>2013-04-29T12:00:29.895Z</wsu:Expires>
</t:Lifetime>
<wsp:AppliesTo>     
<EndpointReference>
<Address>urn:orin.converse</Address>
</EndpointReference></wsp:AppliesTo>
<t:RequestedSecurityToken>    
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
         aHR0cCUzYSUyZiUyZnNjaGVtYWd0Sjk0JTNk
   </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get using this code

```
NSRange divRange = [content rangeOfString:@"<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (divRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSRange endDivRange;

        endDivRange.location = divRange.length + divRange.location;
        endDivRange.length   = [content length] - endDivRange.location;
        endDivRange = [content rangeOfString:@"</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:endDivRange];

        if (endDivRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            divRange.location += divRange.length;
            divRange.length  = endDivRange.location - divRange.location;


            NSLog(@"BinarySecurityToken : %@",[content substringWithRange:divRange]);
        }
    }
```

**Output : 
aHR0cCUzYSUyZiUyZnNjaGVtYWd0Sjk0JTNk**

Comment: <wsse:BinarySecurityToken> it has some attribute,that also printing with the token.Can you please help me to remove that?

Answer (score 1):

You need and XML parser for that.

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)

Comment: +1 I agree that Hpple (which is really the subject tutorial in your link) is a good HTML parser. I only comment to qualify your answer, because some XML parsers will not handle HTML as gracefully. But my experience is that Hpple does a good job.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you can get the ranges of `<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>` and `</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>`, construct new range that will provide you location of the token, and get substring in that range.

Sample code:

```
NSRange openingTagRange = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>"];
NSRange closingTagRange = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>"];
NSRange tokenRange = NSMakeRange(openingTagRange.location + openingTagRange.length, closingTagRange.location - (openingTagRange.location + openingTagRange.length));
NSString *token = [htmlString substringWithRange:tokenRange];
```

Since your input comes from outside, you should probably check if the ranges' locations are not equal to NSNotFound.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,Can you please show me sample code?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSData  * data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    TFHpple * tutorialsParser       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];

    NSString *query = @"//div[@id='BinarySecurityToken']";
    NSArray *nodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:query];

    for (TFHppleElement * element in nodes) {
        NSLog(@"%@", element);
        NSLog(@"%@", [element tagName]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [element attributes]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [element children]);
        for (TFHppleElement *childElement in [element children]) {
                NSLog(@"%@", childElement);
        }
    }
```

hope this will help you [For more try this blog](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/parsing-html-iphone-development/) and [Git Project Resource may help you](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)  and
[Good blog by RAYWENDERLICH](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)

or another option if you have all the HTML data in `NSString` you can get data between specific `NSString` with this function.

```
-(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString)end {
    NSRange startRange = [self rangeOfString:start];
    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange targetRange;
        targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        targetRange.length = [self length] - targetRange.location;   
        NSRange endRange = [self rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];
        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) {
           targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
           return [self substringWithRange:targetRange];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```