# ios - How to parse HTML file?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm getting HTML content in below format.

```
wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id=&quot;uuid:07747f2a-4be4-48fa-9654-5e12235f6040&quot; ValueType=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/11/swt-token-profile-1.0&quot; EncodingType=&quot;http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary&quot; xmlns:wsu=&quot;http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot; xmlns:wsse=&quot;http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd&quot;>
aHR0cCUzYSUyZiUyZnNjaGVtYXMubWNk&lt;/wsse:BinarySecurityToken>&lt;
```

In the below code I'm getting 
            wsu:Id="uuid:07747f2a-4be4-48fa-9654-5e12235f6040" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/11/swt-token-profile-1.0&quot; EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary&quot; xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot; xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd&quot;>
    aHR0cCUzYSUyZiUyZnNjaGVtYXMubWNk

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
if(_data)
{
    NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Content  :%@",content);

    NSRange divRange = [content rangeOfString:@"wsse:BinarySecurityToken" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (divRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSRange endDivRange;

        endDivRange.location = divRange.length + divRange.location;
        endDivRange.length   = [content length] - endDivRange.location;
        endDivRange = [content rangeOfString:@"=&lt;" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:endDivRange];

        if (endDivRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            divRange.location += divRange.length;
            divRange.length  = endDivRange.location - divRange.location;


            NSLog(@"BinarySecurityToken : %@",[content substringWithRange:divRange]);
        }
    }

    [webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:_url];

}
```

}

I want the Output as aHR0cCUzYSUyZiUyZnNjaGVtYXMubWNk.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yesterday You Accepted the same Answer now what  ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566129/ios-how-to-parse-html-content-in-ios

Comment: <wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id=&quot;> it has some attribute,that also printing with the token.Can you please help me to remove that?

Comment: Use my method nd call it using `NSString *token = [self stringBetweenString:@"sse:BinarySecurityToken>" andString:@"</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>"];`

Comment: stringBetweenString is not working,anyway thanks a lot Bunty

Comment: What is all about is it working for you young man ?

Comment: I changed the start position and end position and now it's working fine,thanks for your great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discussing you have `NSString *token = @"<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>aHR0cCUzYSUyZiUyZnNjaGVtYWd0Sjk0JTNk</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>";`
and what the token between tags then you can replace the unwanted character like .

`NSString  *str = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>"
                                     withString:@""];`;

and then

`NSString  *correctToken = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>"
                                     withString:@""];`;